# Does $T^s w = \sum \lambda_i^s \langle w, v_i \rangle v_i$ hold for self-adjoint operators $T$?

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have an Hilbert space $H$ and a compact, self-adjoint linear operator $T: H \to H$. It has an orthonormal eigenbasis $(v_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. Furthermore, assume $T$ is strictly positive, so $\lambda_i > 0$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$.
Suppose $s \in \mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary. We can define $T^s$ through the spectral family, but I am wondering if this also corresponds to just applying this exponent to the eigenvalues, i.e. does it hold that for any $w = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \langle w, v_i \rangle v_i \in H$ we have
$$
T^s w = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_i^s \langle w, v_i \rangle v_i
$$
whenever $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_i^{2s} \langle w, v_i \rangle^2 < \infty$ (in case of $s < 0$)?

It seems like such a natural thing, but I couldn't find the corresponding result in Rudin.

Comment: $\lambda_i^{s}$ is not well-defined if $\lambda_i <0$.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add the assumption that $T$ is positive.

Comment: Applying functions to operators can be formalised in compact-self-adjoint functional calculus. It turns out to define a bounded linear operator when the function you wish to apply (in your case $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = x^s$) is well defined on the spectrum of $T$ and is bounded over there. The only caveat is that eigenvalue 0 is not usually written explicitly in that expression, but it should appear in $T^s$'s when $f(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: Since $f(x)=x^s$ is $\textit{not}$ bounded for positive reals when $s<0$ if $0$ is one of the numbers in $T$'s spectrum (which happens whenever its domain is infinite-dimensional); in such case this approach fails.